# "Requested entity was not found. " while working with searchconsole

Tags: php, laravel, google-search-console

i used to run the request to get data mobileFriendlyTest from googlesearchconsole, from https://console.cloud.google.com/apis

i did run :

```
$request = new Request('POST', 'https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlTestingTools/mobileFriendlyTest:run?key='.$api_key, $headers, $body);
```

i thought its a problem related to the validation of the api key, so i created a new one in a new project, but it remains the same problem..

any solution please, this is the error i got :

> Client error: `POST https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlTestingTools/mobileFriendlyTest:run?key=xxxxx%60 resulted in a` 404 Not Found` response: { "error": { "code": 404,
> "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "status": "NOT_FOUND" }
> }

Comment: 404 Not Found response normally means that the URL you are trying to access is incorrect or that the resource you are trying to get  does not exist. Kindly cross check the API endpoint